# Is there any record of spousal abuse in the written or oral tradition?

Tags: marriage, torts-damages

Is there any example of physical spousal abuse anywhere in tanach or shas?

Comment: here is some reading which makes passing reference to anecdotes http://www.shemayisrael.com/rabbiforsythe/shalombayis/treatspouse.htm

Comment: To answer the question in your title (which doesn't specify physical abuse), there are several examples in the Talmud of rabbis' wives abusing their husbands (see for e.g. *Y'vamos* 63a,b).

Comment: See http://torahmusings.com/2012/06/wife-beating-in-jewish-law-ii/

Answer (score 0):

The mishna in Kesubos describes a series of psychological abuses, all of which are grounds for divorce (and Tosfos says actually, the rabbi should step in and recommend it). For instance, "I demand that you tell the neighbors some deeply-intimate details about yourself." It doesn't really spend time on physical abuse.

There are feminists who claim that physical abuse was so common the Mishna just ignored it; I think it's far more likely that there was no need to address it because it was unheard-of. Or at least obvious from the discussions of psychological abuse.

Comment: It's more accurate to say that the concept of physical abuse didn't really exist.  If you damaged a person, you damaged them had and to fix it, pay damages etc... But what we call physical abuse today, back then, was called discipline.

Comment: @Avi -- says who?!!!! Ptooey!! Rambam says if you slap someone in the face, even if there's no long-term damage (i.e. you can go back to work the next day just fine), you still pay for pain and embarrassment. Why is this different?

Comment: @Avi Rambam says that if a woman says "I insist on sitting around the house, remaining married to my husband, getting fed by him, but doing no chores whatsoever", that *they* -- i.e. the courts -- could compel her to do so, even with a strap if necessary. Not that the husband could take that into his own hands, G-d forbid! (Rav Kapach, zt'l, makes this point.)

Comment: really? The courts come to the person's house and hits them with a strap everytime they sit down?

Comment: @Avi ask Rav Kapach, his point not mine. The language is *kofin*, not *kofeh.* Presumably she is called into court, told that if she insists on staying in this marriage and being supported, she needs to do *something*, whipped by a professional if the courts feel that's necessary to get the message across, and then sent home. If she pulls this shtick too much he could simply divorce her. And recall that Rambam writes as soon as she says "I can't stand to be in the bedroom with my husband", she can demand a divorce too.

Comment: Unless you wish for me to violat a halacha, I can not ask Rav Kapach.  However, his point is likely that the husband would have to get a court order to discipline his wife before doing so himself.

Comment: @Avi I'd seen an article citing Rav Kapach's writings; his point specifically is that *kofin* means "we compel", and not *kofeh* that he compels -- he is not allowed to hit her.

Comment: @avi Shalom is correct; the Rambam is obviously referring to a court: ודבר זה כפי מה שיראה הדיין. (This is also evident in many other instances in *Hil. Ishus* where the word "*kofin*" is used). And there are lots of things for which a person could theoretically be disciplined by a court. That doesn't mean that agents of the court would go around surveilling people and breaking into their homes to administer punishment. But, under the right circumstances, a court was empowered to compel people to fulfill their obligations.